# Impossible to initialize choromecast web api in google chrome

Tags: web-applications, chromecast

I am trying to implement chromecast in a video player but I can't initialize the chromecast API and I can't understand why.

This is the code that I am using taken from the google official page.

```
window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function(isAvailable) {
 if (isAvailable) {
   initializeCastApi();
 }
```

};

The isAvailable parameter is always false so the cast api is not loaded even if the callback to the __onGCastApiAvailable is firing.

I tried on a setInterval to check if chrome.cast is loaded but it is always undefined.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(chrome.cast); // it is always undefined
}, 1000);
```

Do I need to install something in Chrome, I do have the cast button in the menu and I can cast fine the browser.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] is only trigged if the sender app (your webpage) is hosted with https. If you are trying this with http, it will silently fail and chrome.cast will be undefined.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Hmm, still giving `false` to me, even though I'm hosting locally with self-signed certificate

Comment: Oops, I was using Firefox, that was my issue...